# api django, como mostrar varias tablas de una base de datos

Tags: django, reactjs, api, djangorestframework, react-axios

Tengo una API con *DJango* en la cual ya puedo consultar, agregar, modificar o eliminar artículos usando *reactjs*, por ejemplo para leer los artículos con *axios*.

```
 axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ 
                type: act.TRAE_DATA, 
                payload: response.data
            }) 
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Con eso después almaceno el response en mi store y puedo mostrar todos los artículos, también puedo usar post, delete, put para crear, actualizar o eliminar artículos. Hasta aquí no tengo problema ya que la API funciona bien.

Lo que no se como implementar, si ahora quiero tener la funcionalidad de registrar también clientes, se que debo crear las clase Clients en *models.py* pero que tengo que hacer en *serializers.py* para que poder interactuar con clientes de la misma forma que con artículos.

Ahora esto es lo que tengo en mi API:

### models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    npart = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    categ = models.TextField()
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    desc = models.TextField()
```

---

### serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('id','name', 'npart', 'categ', 'cost', 'qty', 'desc')
```

---

### views.py

```
class ProducViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

Comment: A como entendí tu pregunta, tendrías que hacer lo mismo que hiciste con productos, no sería necesario cambiar nada, o bien ¿quieres hacer un registro doble, cuando registres los clientes quieres hacer un registro de producto?

Comment: ?? Pues crea el serializer y el modelviewset y registra los urls. Y agrega la app al settings. etc.